# Geometric probability - meeting

Tags: probability

3 people are to arrive at the same location some time between 3pm and 4pm. They arrive at random times within the hour and only stay for ten minutes. Since they only go one time, what is the probability that they will meet during that hour?

Comment: How are the times distributed? uniformly? The probability that all 3 will meet at one point in time?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15448/probability-of-two-people-meeting?rq=1 and tried applying it to your case? Instead of a square, since you have 3 people, maybe try a cube? (so for n people, you'd use an n-dimensional unit cube)

Comment: Yes, the probability tahat all 3 will meet at one point in time.